# Select data() values as an array of all selected inputs

Tags: jquery

How do I select data() values as an array of all selected inputs?  My non-working attempt is shown below.  If the first and last input is checked, I want `data` to be `["extra1","extra3"]`.

https://jsfiddle.net/4mmm6azt/

```
$('#go').click(function() {
  var data = $('#mytable tbody input:checked').data('extra').serializeArray();
  console.log('data', data);
});

<table id='mytable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-extra="extra1" name="id[]"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="2" data-extra="extra2" name="id[]"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="3" data-extra="extra3" name="id[]"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) at this context,

```
$('#go').click(function() {
  var data = $('#mytable tbody input:checked').map(function(){  
    return $(this).data("extra");
  }).get();
  console.log('data', data);
});
```

Comment: Perfect.  I've never used `map()` before.  See https://jsfiddle.net/4mmm6azt/1/ for a working example.

Comment: @user1032531 Glad to help! :)